# Using Doctrine in D8

Tags: 8

I have downloaded the latest version of Drupal 8 my project structure looks like:

```
private/
  EntityOne.php 
  EntityTwo.php
  Test.php => Test Script (Eventually AUT)
public/
  index.php => Drupal Engine
```

Inside Test.php I wish to begin building a series of entities which at first will be used externally and eventually be moved into Drupal modules.

I have Googled and spent hours trying to get Doctrine to start letting me build tables with my entities, but I am doing something wrong.

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html#obtaining-the-entitymanager

Is of no help, there is no **"vendor/autoload.php"**  but there is a **"core/vendor/autoload.php"**

I can include this file in Test.php and everything is fine but when I start adding code:

```
  include '../public/core/vendor/autoload.php';

  use Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup;
  use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

  // Create a simple "default" Doctrine ORM configuration for Annotations
  $isDevMode = true;
  $config = Setup::createAnnotationMetadataConfiguration(array(__DIR__."/src"), $isDevMode);
```

I get an error:

Fatal error: Class 'Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup' not found in ...\private\index.php on line 10

There is no **"Doctrine/ORM"**

What am I missing???

Alex

Comment: D8 supports Doctrine ORM? Really?! I thought that had been chucked out? I can't see any of the ORM classes under vendor/doctrine, just the `Doctrine\Common` namespace...

Comment: Ya apparently, I just read a blog that stated this...they use the annotations or something but not the ORM itself...why wouldn't they leave it for people like me :(

Comment: Yep that sounds familiar :/

Comment: As far as I know Drupal 8 does not have the full Doctrine ORM setup, just a bunch of small parts. So the `Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Setup` doesn't actually exist. If you want it you'll have to manually add it.

Answer (score 5):

Drupal 8 uses the annotation reader from Doctrine Common but it does not use the ORM. The handbook page for the Drupal entity field API is being written at https://drupal.org/node/2078191

Comment: Yes, Drupal's Entity Field API has nothing to do with Doctrine.

Comment: Potentially though you could write a doctrine based entity storage controller, which than would allow you to go to PSRCR or whatever.

Comment: why wouldn't they use doctrine? couldn't standardization be good, I want to try drupal, because it could be faster than symfony, but it is looking like some key components are going to be different huh

Comment: Drupal wants to do everything different. They don't stick to PSR-2 either. Unfortunately, they want to be leaders and drivers in the PHP community, but the Drupal community isn't big enough to have that impact. For what it's worth, the product is still useful, but you have to become familiar with the way they do stuff, and many times, you'll see that the decision was not right, so it can change too.